# Como crear una biblia en WPF con visual studio 2019 framework 4.5.1, soy amateur

Tags: wpf

Saludos a todos esta es mi primera publicación, quiero hacer una aplicación de la biblia reina Valera en C#, conozco lo básico en vb pero como desapareció ahora estoy entrándole a C# así que lo hare aquí en C#, he podido obtener la biblia en formato de texto en el siguiente formato:

1  1  1 En el principio creó .....

es decir los libros, los capítulos y los versículos están en números, todo el documento tiene 4 digamos campos separados por tab como se ve en el ejemplo lineas arriba. seleccionare los libros y capítulos con un listbox, LA PREGUNTA cual es la mejor manera de moverme por toda la biblia que es un archivo de texto, no tengo idea, si lo lleno dentro de un List o crear una tabla virtual no se como le llamaran, todos los versículos de un capitulo se mostraran en un ListBox, que alternativas puedo usar?, los Linq seria bueno pero donde lo pongo todo el texto para hacer las consultas... saludos y espero haberme explicado bien.

PD: el sql y todas sus herramientas estan dentro del framework 4.5.1?, ya que no quisiera instalar otras aplicaciones aparte, basta con ejecutarla en windows desde la 8 sin problemas, saludos

Answer (score 0):

acabo de hacerlo en visual basic, porque c# todavia no lo agarro bien, asi que esta, lo hice con un listbox y un textblok.
les comparto el codigo porque me salio un aviso que decia me estaba quedando sin memoria y creo que era la t.de video, porque se queria colgar la pc,  por eso pongo todo el codigo aunque es muy simple quizas no sea la mejor forma o la más optima en recursos. como lo harian? parece que consume mucho recurso, esta hecho en wpf framework 4.5.1. quisiera saber si estoy usando las herramientas correctas o este metodo consume muchos recursos de la pc, como optimzarlo?.... saludos

```
Class MainWindow
Dim Textos As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
Dim libros() As String = {"Génesis", "Éxodo", "Levítico", "Números", "Deuteronomio", "Josué", "Jueces", "Rut", "1 Samuel", "2 Samuel", "1 Reyes", "2 Reyes", "1 Crónicas", "2 Crónicas", "Esdras", "Nehemías", "Ester", "Job", "Salmos", "Proverbios", "Eclesiastés", "Cantares", "Isaías", "Jeremías", "Lamentaciones", "Ezequiel", "Daniel", "Oseas", "Joel", "Amós", "Abdías", "Jonás", "Miqueas", "Nahum", "Habacuc", "Sofonías", "Hageo", "Zacarías", "Malaquías", "Mateo", "Marcos", "Lucas", "Juan", "Hechos", "Romanos", "1 Corintios", "2 Corintios", "Gálatas", "Efesios", "Filipenses", "Colosenses", "1 Tesalonicenses", "2 Tesalonicenses", "1 Timoteo", "2 Timoteo", "Tito", "Filemón", "Hebreos", "Santiago", "1 Pedro", "2 Pedro", "1 Juan", "2 Juan", "3 Juan", "Judas", "Apocalipsis"}
Dim libro, capitulo, v As String
Dim l() As String
Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    For Each a As String In My.Resources.TablaBiblia_2.Split(vbLf)
        l = a.Split(vbTab)
        Textos.Add(l(0), l(1))
    Next
    LstBPanel.ItemsSource = libros
End Sub
Private Sub TextBlock_MouseLeftButtonUp(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
    LstBPanel.ItemsSource = libros
    LstBPanel.Tag = "1"
    capitulo = ""
    libro = ""
    LstBPanel.Style = FindResource("ListBoxStyle1")
    ScrollViewer.SetHorizontalScrollBarVisibility(LstBPanel, ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden)
    ScrollViewer.SetHorizontalScrollBarVisibility(LstBPanel, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled)
End Sub
Private Sub LstBPanel_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles LstBPanel.SelectionChanged
    If LstBPanel.SelectedIndex = -1 Then Return
    Select Case LstBPanel.Tag
        Case "1"
            Me.Title = Choose(LstBPanel.SelectedIndex + 1, libros)
            libro = (LstBPanel.SelectedIndex + 1) & ","
            v = (From x In Textos Where x.Key.Remove(libro.Length) = libro Select x.Key).Last
            v = v.Remove(v.IndexOf(":"))
            v = v.Substring(v.IndexOf(",") + 1)
            LstBPanel.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, CInt(v))
            LstBPanel.Tag = "2"
            LstBPanel.SelectedIndex = -1
        Case "2"
            Me.Title = Me.Title & " " & (LstBPanel.SelectedIndex + 1)
            capitulo = libro & (LstBPanel.SelectedIndex + 1) & ":"
            v = (From y In Textos Where y.Key.Remove(y.Key.LastIndexOf(":") + 1) = capitulo Select y.Key).Last
            v = v.Substring(v.LastIndexOf(":") + 1)
            LstBPanel.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(1, CInt(v))
            LstBPanel.Tag = "3"
            LstBPanel.SelectedIndex = -1
        Case "3"
            LstBPanel.Style = FindResource("ListBoxStyle2")
            Dim p = LstBPanel.SelectedIndex
            LstBPanel.ItemsSource = From y In Textos Where y.Key.Remove(y.Key.LastIndexOf(":") + 1) = capitulo Select y.Key.Substring(y.Key.IndexOf(",") + 1).PadLeft(7, " ") & "   " & y.Value.Trim
            LstBPanel.SelectedIndex = p
            LstBPanel.ScrollIntoView(LstBPanel.Items(p))
            ScrollViewer.SetHorizontalScrollBarVisibility(LstBPanel, ScrollBarVisibility.Visible)
    End Select
End Sub
```

End Class